# Python/kivy : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have 2 file test.py and test.kv. When I run test.py and pass numeric value in `self.abc.text=10` then it gives error
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/textinput.py", line 2930, in _set_text
     text = text.replace(u'\r\n', u'\n')
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

If I pass string value then it's working. I think text for string value but I don't what is for numeric value?

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
#Window.maximize()
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode

Window.size = (500, 530)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    groupName = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)
    abc = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        self.abc.text=10



class Group(App):


    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    groupName: groupName
    abc:abc
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Number'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: abc

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Test'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: groupName
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
```

Comment: Where in your code does the exception get triggered?

Comment: @Atto Allas  when i pass integer value in self.abc.text=10 then it trigger error.

Comment: It might be because it's expecting a string. Try changing `10` to `"10"`

Comment: @Atto Allas yes but i want send integer value.

Comment: @Atto Allas actually it coming from database then how to pass it as string cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id`=?", (1,))
        rows = cur.fetchone()
        rows[1]=10
        self.abc.text =rows[1]

Comment: Could I ask why? Surely you could just convert it back into an int if you really needed an int?

Comment: You would type `self.abc.text = str(rows[1])`

Comment: I'll put an answer, then accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NumericProperty` and then `str(root.abc)` in kv.
Try this example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    abc = NumericProperty(0)

    def set_text(self):
        self.abc = 42



KV = """

MyBoxLayout:

    Button:
        text: str(root.abc)
        on_release:
            root.set_text()

"""


class Testapp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return root


Testapp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to type `self.abc.text = str(rows[1])` in order for it to be passed as the correct type.

Hope this helps!